# Building an answer file

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to automate the running of a diagcab file via command line or PowerShell. I understand you can run a diagcab via command line from the details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424379.aspx), however I am unsure how to compose the answer file to use.

The Diagcab file is MicrosoftEasyFix25010.mini.diagcab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from here: https://superuser.com/questions/871822/creating-an-answer-file-for-windowsupdatediagnostic-diagcab-in-eclipse-wtp is to use the Get-TroubleshootingPack cmdlet to generate it.

Comment: Thank you, Why i can't find this on MS forums or docs i have no idea.